# Make json string from form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hey guys I have a form where the output is saved in database.
What I want is to save it in a json string and show the string.

```
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <select name="gender" >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Man">Man</option>
        <option value="Vrouw">Vrouw</option>
    </select>
    adress:<br>
  <input type="text" name="adress">
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>   


  {
    "PersonalData" : {
        "Gender" : [value of gender]
        "FirstName" : "[valeu of firstname]",
        "adress" : "[valeu of adress]",
}
```

Comment: Which programming language you are using?

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery

Comment: I use classic asp but  i want it to do it with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Create a JSONObject and add all the values you want into it with the put() method. Then you can use the .toString() function to turn it into a string.

Comment: `JSON` is a string format, not a JavaScript object

Comment: There's a class called JSONObject in Java, assumed it'd be useful and available here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var result = {};
  var PersonalData = {};
  
  $("#submitt").click(function(){
    PersonalData.FirstName = $('#first').val();
    PersonalData.Address = $('#address').val();
    PersonalData.Gender = $("#gender option:selected").text();
    
    result.PersonalData = PersonalData;
    console.log(result);
    var resultString = result.toString();
    console.log(resultString);
  });
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <select name="gender" id="gender" >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Man">Man</option>
        <option value="Vrouw">Vrouw</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Address:<br>
  <input type="text" name="adress" id="address">
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit!" id="submitt" />
</div>
```